# Add JQuery in .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a .js file with jquery inside but I do not know how to add jquery. I do not want to install it from the external .html but directly from the .js file.

Thanks

Comment: Uhm, I suggest to read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to link jQuery with a CDN or other `<script></script>` tags in your html but rather include the entire library in your main js file,

Go to his link:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js

And copy past code there into your JavaScript file.

The javascript there is the entire jQuery library compressed for efficiency. Include your own code that requires jQuery after it.

#### This is not a best practice and is hard to maintain.

I advise including jQuery in your project through a cdn like so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Personally, I like to be lazy and go with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>` since I want every update.

Comment: @Luxelin its not a best practice since future updates could break your  app.

Comment: That's actually part of the reason I do it (to force myself to fix the issue if something happens).